# Wordpress, adding custom scripts, in correct way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have to convert a theme built in HTML/CSS, into a Wordpress Theme. I'm quite new in Wordpress. The first what came in my mind for adding custom scripts to my theme was like in example bellow:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Superslides Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.superslides.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<!-- ScrollBar Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- Masonry Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fancybox Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<!-- Settings Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/settings.js"></script>
```

But I believe this is not the correct way to add them, so I found another solution, but I'm not sure, if I wrote it correct, so next code I wrote is in the `functions.php` file:

```
    // Always use wp_enqueue_scripts action hook to both enqueue and register scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_and_register_my_scripts' );

function enqueue_and_register_my_scripts(){

    // Use `get_stylesheet_directoy_uri() if your script is inside your theme or child theme.
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.superslides.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/settings.js' );

    // Let's enqueue a script only to be used on a specific page of the site
    if ( is_page( 'careers' ) ){

        // Enqueue a script that has both jQuery (automatically registered by WordPress)
        // and my-script (registered earlier) as dependencies.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-careers-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-careers-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'my-script' ) );
    }
}
```

If this is the right way to do it, then I have to call:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_scripts(); ?>
```

in the `header.php` file?
If this is not the correct way to add multiple scripts to a Wordpress theme, please let me know, what I'm doing wrong, I'll appreciate it a lot...!
Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `wp_register_script` is the correct way to register a script for inclusion on a page, but doesn't enqueue it and link it on the page - use `wp_enqueue_script` for that (it uses [similar parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) but registers *and* adds it to the page at the right time ). If you use `wp_register_script` first, you must also at some time call `wp_enqueue_script` for it to actually be added to the page. You do not need to call `enqueue_and_register_my_scripts` at any time: adding it to the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action is enough.

Finally, you must give each of those scripts you want to register/enqueue its own *unique* id: currently you're registering them all as 'my-script' and each is overwriting the previous script.

Comment: so after every `wp_register_script` I'll add a line with:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );` ? Right?
If no, can u give me one example? How I do that?

Comment: You can either do that or just use `wp_enqueue_script` by itself: it's accepted parameters are exactly the same as `wp_register_script` and will itself register the script if it hasn't been already. And again, you must use unique ids for each script; naming them all `my-script` will only ultimately enqueue the last one.